# in the school database course they teaches us with oracle database & i have a macbook what is the best replacement database to use?

Tags: oracle, replace

[image]
in the school database course they teaches us with oracle database & i have a macbook what is the best replacement database to use?

Comment: If you can't run a VM (best thing for you IMHO!) or a free tier somewhere (2nd best), take a good hard look at PostgreSQL - it's by far the best Open Source db out there!

Comment: I use MacOS x86 and Oracle Database (..and PostgreSQL and every other technology  too). Why do you want a replacement database? Oracle Database is awesome! Run it in docker. There are great resources online. If you have ARM architecture, Oracle Database is also available on this architecture. Another option is OCI. Sign up and run the database and all tooling. Their "Always Free" offer is the best among hyperscalers. Nothing to be paid.

Answer (score 2):

If the focus of the course is on basic SQL, you can use almost whatever database you have. MariaDB and PostgreSQL are free to use, and are widely used in industry too. Both are available for MacOS.

If the focus of the course is on Oracle features such as PL/SQL or native Oracle tools, your best bet is to run a Linux VM that hosts Oracle. It should also be possible to use a Docker image for running Oracle, but since there isn't native MacOS support, the image will contain Linux bits and pieces and AFAIK is pretty hacky.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your requirements and what they want you to *do* with the database, you might consider the Oracle Autonomous Transaction Processing (ATP) database available in the free tier of Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. You would need Internet access, but you could run Oracle 19c or later and have all of the same client tools like SQL Developer available for use.

If you need to do specific things that can only be done with a local database, then use Oracle Virtual Box to create an Oracle Linux VM. I've seen examples that run the Intel x86 version of Linux without a separate hardware emulator, but haven't tried it myself. You may find that you need a separate emulator to run the Intel version of the OS on a Mac. Once you have the VM running, install Oracle software. Note that many online examples of VM creation will use Ubuntu, but make sure you use Oracle Linux, as Ubuntu is not supported for Oracle Database server.